# Speed up write numpy data in binary to file. ply generator

Tags: python, numpy, mesh

I made my own ply exporter and even though it is working, it is quite slow. I'm assuming that the problem comes from specifically looping over the elements and, based on [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10535687/write-a-raw-binary-file-with-numpy-array-data#comment57449464_10539119), from using `struct.pack`.

The challenge with exporting `Nodes` is that it is a 1D vector of tuples. The challenge with exporting `Faces` is that each line of `int`s is preceded by a number "3" in `uchar` format.

I put the entire code here since it serves as a MWE and also a reference if someone wants to use the code to export meshes in ply format.

Code:

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
import struct
import timeit

def Timeme(funct,var,NN=10,NNN=10):
    for i in xrange(NN):
        start =timeit.default_timer()
        for t in xrange(NNN):
            funct(*var)
        end =timeit.default_timer()
        print str(i)+': '+str((end - start)/NNN*1000)  

# This function is fictitious. In reality the 
# Nodes array is imported from another module
def MakeNodes(Nr,Nc):
    Nodes=np.zeros(Nr*Nc,dtype=[('x', np.float32), ('y', np.float32), ('z', np.float32)])
    x = np.linspace(0, (Nc-1), Nc, dtype=np.float32)
    y = np.linspace((Nr-1),0 , Nr, dtype=np.float32)
    xv, yv = np.meshgrid(x, y, sparse=False, indexing='xy')
    Nodes['x']=xv.flatten()
    Nodes['y']=yv.flatten()
    Nodes['z']=(1/2-((Nodes['x']/Nc-1/2)**2+ (Nodes['y']/Nr-1/2)**2))*Nr/2
    return Nodes

# Function below explained in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44934631
def MakeFaces(Nr,Nc):
    out = np.empty((Nr-1,Nc-1,2,3),dtype=int)
    r = np.arange(Nr*Nc).reshape(Nr,Nc)
    l1=r[:-1,:-1]
    l2=r[:-1,1:]
    l3=r[1:,:-1]
    l4=r[1:,1:]
    out[:,:, 0,0] = l2
    out[:,:, 0,1] = l1
    out[:,:, 0,2] = l3
    out[:,:, 1,0] = l4
    out[:,:, 1,1] = l2
    out[:,:, 1,2] = l3
    out.shape =(-1,3)
    return out

def ExportPlyBinary(Nodes,Faces,file):
    LN=len(Nodes)
    LF=len(Faces)

    header= \
    "ply\n" \
    "format binary_little_endian 1.0\n" \
    "element vertex "+str(LN)+"\n" \
    "property float x\n" \
    "property float y\n" \
    "property float z\n" \
    "element face "+str(LF)+"\n" \
    "property list uchar int vertex_indices\n" \
    "end_header\n"

    with open(file, 'wb') as fp:
        fp.write(header)
        s = struct.Struct('<fff')
        for nd in Nodes:
            fp.write(s.pack(nd['x'],nd['y'],nd['z']))

        s = struct.Struct('<Blll')
        for fc in Faces:
            fp.write(s.pack(3,fc[0],fc[1],fc[2]))

Nr=200
Nc=200
Nodes=MakeNodes(Nr,Nc)
Faces=MakeFaces(Nr,Nc)
Timeme(ExportPlyBinary,(Nodes,Faces,"Test.ply"))
Timeme(np.savez,("Test_np.ply", Nodes,Faces))
```

Result:

```
0: 366.352801235
1: 386.216017627
2: 383.307741944
3: 359.598214393
4: 363.434228045
5: 397.255473919
6: 433.967095136
7: 407.806616677
8: 393.701390596
9: 379.542319143
0: 15.5258007875
1: 13.2543344563
2: 12.8754439597
3: 24.2303215372
4: 15.9684973291
5: 14.2023306048
6: 13.7465456437
7: 13.6964054484
8: 21.27484093
9: 13.2139143373
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked `Trimesh` as suggested by @max9111 and was able to create a more efficient function. The key ideas (in my understanding) are (1) the conversion to the correct data type and order by creating a new array and (2) the use of the `.tostring` function. I initially avoided this direction as it seemed to waste memory but at this point the advantages are clear. Note that my `Nodes` array is ready to have `.tostring` applied to it, but I though I would keep the solution more general.

```
def NewExportPlyBinary(Nodes,Faces,file):
    LN=len(Nodes)
    LF=len(Faces)

    header= \
    "ply\n" \
    "format binary_little_endian 1.0\n" \
    "element vertex "+str(LN)+"\n" \
    "property float x\n" \
    "property float y\n" \
    "property float z\n" \
    "element face "+str(LF)+"\n" \
    "property list uchar int vertex_indices\n" \
    "end_header\n"

    dtype_vertex = [('vertex', '<f4', (3))]
    vertex = np.empty(LN, dtype=dtype_vertex)
    vertex['vertex']=np.stack((Nodes['x'],Nodes['y'],Nodes['z']),axis=-1)

    # vertex=Nodes

    dtype_face = [('count', '<u1'),('index', '<i4', (3))]
    faces = np.empty(LF, dtype=dtype_face)
    faces['count'] = 3
    faces['index'] = Faces

    with open(file, 'wb') as fp:
        fp.write(header)
        fp.write(vertex.tostring())
        fp.write(faces.tostring())
```

I now get the following times for the 200x200 example:

```
0: 373.361611377 # original ExportPlyBinary
0: 20.5686725792 # numpy's savez
0: 4.85469689001 # NewExportPlyBinary
```

Note: the difference between `savez` and `NewExportPlyBinary` basically vanishes when the problem size increases.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use what is available?

For example trimesh?
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/trimesh

Even when you wan't only a small part of the package you can copy and adjust this part from their source code. (with mentioning the authors of course)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I was able to get a fast solution by exploring trimesh.